# Not able to understand WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN functionality

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow

Not able to understand WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN, which is introduced in Android M. .However the definition in android developer site is very ambiguous.Please anyone clarify about this varible

Answer (score 1):

WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN - is the defined user wifi configuration state (true means its locked, false means its changeable).

from android documentation :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html

> This setting controls whether WiFi configurations created by a Device
>   Owner app should be locked down (that is, be editable or removable
>   only by the Device Owner App, not even by Settings app).

since Marshmallow this configurations have been changed and now are accessible only if you produce your own configuration per application using specific API's.

please refer to Android 6.0 Changes.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html

> Your apps can now change the state of WifiConfiguration objects only
>   if you created these objects. You are not permitted to modify or
>   delete WifiConfiguration objects created by the user or by other apps.

hope it clarifies a bit.

Comment: Daniel Netzer :You mean to say if the variable "WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN" is set then we can't modify/delete the Wifi SSID manually from the device if we remove device owner permission from the app.

Comment: Is that the variable "WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN" is set then we can't modify/delete the Wifi SSID manually from the device if we remove device owner permission from the app.Is my understanding is correct??

Comment: thats true, if its set your app cant change the Wifi SSID manually.

Comment: @DanielNetzer Is there a way to modify this flag? I know you can't ask for permissions in the manifest for modifying secure settings unless you are a system app, but can you do it if you make your app a device administrator, for example?